# Pivoting a simple table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, etl

I have a simple two-column table, which I want to pivot the rows into columns, so that this table:

```
List      Count   
----      -----
Bugs        3   
Changes     5
```

Can look like this table:

```
Bugs    Changes
----     -----
 3         5
```

I have attempted the pivot using an ETL Tool of Uncollapsing Columns, but keep ending up with this:

```
Bugs    Changes
----     -----
 3        null 
null       5
```

Is there any way to do this pivot in SQL?

Comment: Did  you try to click on the [pivot] tag?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code - or just rotate your monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do aggregation like that :

```
select sum(case when List = 'Bugs' then Count else 0 end) as Bugs,
       sum(case when List = 'Changes' then Count else 0 end) as Changes
from table t
where List in ('Bugs', 'Changes');
```

Comment: The pivot worked, but I received a null value in the two columns where I expected the 3 and 5 to be. Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding the where List in ('Bugs', 'Changes'); didn't work for me.

Comment: @BobDuncan. . . I suspect your `List` have name with padded with left spaces.

Comment: Can you clarify @Yogesh? My code looks like this: `select MAX(case when idList = 'Bugs' then curcount end) as Bugs, MAX(case when idList = 'Changes' then curcount end) as Changes FROM tablename where idList in ('Bugs', 'Changes');
`

Comment: @BobDuncan. . . Your codes looks fine and no issue at all could you edit the actual data or structure of table ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Had a spelling error in the strings, thank you very much. The code worked perfectly.